# Uso de select com função SUM()

Tags: sql-server, select

Estou desenvolvendo um banco de Dados para uma pequena aplicação.

Meu banco possui 3 tabelas: alunos, disciplinas e boletim_escolar, este ultimo utilizo para inserir 3 notas individuais.

Consegui calcular a media destas NOTAS através da função SUM() até aí tudo, minha dificuldade está em exibir as três notas da TABELA seguida deste resultado da função SUM().

Como faço isso corretamente? Estou usando o SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

-- select da tabela de notas

```
SELECT * FROM boletim_escolar
```

-- função que calcular a MÉDIA DE CADA ALUNO – Moisés Ramos 7 mins atrás

```
SELECT sum(((nota1*1)+(nota2*1)+(nota3*2))/4) AS 'Media Final' 
FROM boletim_escolar GROUP BY id_codaluno
```

Supondo que a tabela esteja com as notas gostaria de exibir o resultado do SUM() ao lado da coluna nota3

nota1  |  nota2 |  nota3 | Média ???

Será possível fazer isso preciso urgente dessa AJUDA.

Comment: ficar um pouco dificil entende o que você esta tentando fazer sem ter a estrutura das tabelas e seu select. edite sua pergunta com essas informações.

Comment: Moisés, edite sua pergunta e coloque seus cometários na pergunta

Comment: Quer ver o script da tabela? COMO faço para enviar

Comment: `SELECT nota1, nota2, nota3, sum(((nota1*1)+(nota2*1)+(nota3*2))/4) AS 'Media Final' FROM`

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior, isso vai dar erro na certa.

Comment: Este eh o erro : Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'boletim_escolar.nota1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @MoisésRamos, não tem como você exibir a nota para cada linha dessa forma. o fato de você usar o GROUP BY vai agrupa todas a linhas do um usuários isso pode existir muitas linhas, mas se for o caso de ter a média para cada linha então não faz sentido você usa o SUM() basta soma e dividi ou usar o AVG

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza tem razão, não prestei muita atenção. Acredito que se adicionar um `SUM()` a cada nota irá resolver, pois todos os valores ficarão agrupados. Não tinha me atentado ao `GROUP BY` na consulta. `SELECT id_codaluno, SUM(nota1), SUM(nota2), SUM(nota3), "MEDIA" FROM`

Comment: @MoisésRamos um aluno poderá ou terá mais de um `boletim_escolar`?

Comment: Não no primeiro momento.

Comment: Obs. estou calculando a média ponderada onde a ''nota3'' tem peso 2.

Comment: Eu inseri a seguinte consulta : "SELECT sum(nota1*1), sum(nota2*1), sum(nota3*2) AS 'Media Aluno' 
FROM boletim_escolar 
GROUP BY id_codaluno". Ela me retorna apenas o resultado dos cálculos. Seria possível dividir todos estes resultados por 4, queno caso seria a soma das médias ponderadas?

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT sum(nota1) AS 'Media Final' FROM boletim_escolar GROUP BY id_codaluno 

    Decimal N1='Soma da primira nota'*1

    SELECT sum(nota2) AS 'Media Final' FROM boletim_escolar GROUP BY id_codaluno 

    Decimal N2='Soma da segunda nota'*1


    SELECT sum(nota3) AS 'Media Final' FROM boletim_escolar GROUP BY id_codaluno 

    Decimal N3='Soma da 3ª  nota'*2

   decimal  media=(N1+N2+N3)/4
```

QUAL É A LINGUAGEM DE PROGRAMAÇÃO??

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Linguagem (ex:C#,java):  só estas a utilizar o Sql,

Comment: Junto com o vb6.

Comment: No banco de Dados esta ocorrendo este erro: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'boletim_escolar.nota1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: SELECT nota1,nota2,nota3,(sum(nota1)+sum(nota2)+sum(nota3*2))/4  AS 'Media Final'
FROM boletim_escolar
GROUP BY id_codaluno . Este foi o codigo que utilizei

Comment: o objetivo é apresentar uma lista com as médias calculada ?

Comment: Sim eh isso, se puder exemplifique de uma forma genérica

Comment: Só quero exibir as 3 notas e a média

Comment: Para fazer  isso, estas a usar o List<>?

Answer (score 0):

```
select nota1,nota2,nota3,sum(((nota1*1)+(nota2*1)+(nota3*2))/4) AS 'Media Final' 
from boletim_escolar 
GROUP BY id_codaluno
```

Não tinha entendido porque você utiliza o `sum()` em vez do `avg()`, mas depois reparei que as notas possuem peso.

Comment: E como poderia fazer o correto?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei o motivo de você usar a função SUM() uma vez que não tem mais de uma linha para cada usuário, quando na realidade basta usar o **+** para soma os valores.

```
declare @boletim_escolar table
(
    id_codaluno int,
    nota1 numeric(18,2),
    nota2 numeric(18,2),
    nota3 numeric(18,2)
)

insert into @boletim_escolar values
(1, 7.5 , 6.8 , 8.9),
(2, 1.5 , 7.8 , 3.9),
(3, 9.5 , 5.8 , 7.9)

SELECT nota1, (nota1*1) as 'nota1 Ponderada', nota2,  (nota2*1) AS 'nota2 Ponderada' ,
 nota3 ,(nota3*2) AS 'nota3 Ponderada',  
cast((((nota1*1)+(nota2*1)+(nota3*2))/4) as numeric(18,2)) AS 'Media Final Ponderada' 
FROM @boletim_escolar
```

Veja o resoltado abaixo.

```
nota1   nota1 Ponderada nota2   nota2 Ponderada nota3   nota3 Ponderada Media Final Ponderada
7.50    7.50    6.80    6.80    8.90    17.80   8.03
1.50    1.50    7.80    7.80    3.90    7.80    4.28
9.50    9.50    5.80    5.80    7.90    15.80   7.78
```